# ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv partition full for no apparent reason?

Tags: server, partitioning, package-management, mount, disk-usage

I am using ubuntu server on a few machines but it seems 2 of them are afflicted with this issue while the others are totally normal. Both machines are very barebones, outside of the ubuntu server OS there is very few additional installs and nothing which accounts for the massive disk usage.

I tried using tips from previous posts here, checking with `du`, `wajig large`, `ncdu` but nothing shows what is using this vast amount of space. It seems this space is not accounted for at all yet is being blocked from use as if it was full.

Below are images of `df -h` indicating the disk is near-full (deleted some logs to free space from 0 and install ncdu) and the ncdu printout **note `/media` is space utilized by HDD on the server since I mount them there. It does not contain anything from the partition in question so it can be ignored.*

[image: df -h printout]

[image: ncdu]

[image]

Comment: I would use `du` to find the cause; which you've claimed to have done but have provided no proof (just a quick `ncdu` paste). You've provided no release details and vague details (few additional installs; do those installs differ from the boxes where you don't have problems?; that info is likely very much a clue, also are all configs the same between boxes?  esp. regards logging? again no details provided..)  I'd suggest providing some details (not just random pastes).

Comment: No there is nothing noteworthy differing between the machines except the 2 with these issues are the most recent setups of the same configuration. And the pastes aren't random, they're outputs of what I figured would be relevant here. ncdu provides the same general information as `du` doesn't it? That's why I didn't bother to provide it, and I opted for ncdu over du since its more concise for a small image. If you have an idea of where specifically to be checking I'll give it a go but so far none of the blanket checks I've tried seem to provide anything useful as you can see in the images.

Comment: Try "du -sm * | sort -nr | head" while in / directory. You could also check for deleted files, that are still being used by processes by "lsof | grep deleted"

Comment: No luck on deleted files. It only shows the logs which I purged to make install space for ncdu and wajig. The  `du -sm * | sort -nr | head` command you posted gives me this output https://imgur.com/kJSvlsh It seems like this space is not really being utilized based on all of this. The only directory with any significant space being used is a directory I've mounted much larger drives on so there's no installs or anything that would use more than maybe 15-20gb tops.